# Why was there a need for Yona to be saved in a miraculous way?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, fish, yonah-jonah-book-of

What's the deal with Yona being swallowed by a fish (2:1)? Couldn't the same thing (i.e. him realizing his mistake) be achieved if he landed on an island?

Answer (score 3):

Being in a cramped fish, which felt like a grave, caused *Yona* to turn to God in prayer [and repentance]. Source: [*Rashi* to 2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91):1 and :3.

Comment: this can be accomplished without a miracle. there are natural ways to torture a person such as being stuck on a raft in the ocean in the hot sun. or stuck in a desert island without food

Comment: @ray The question wasn't why he was stuck in a fish and not otherwise tortured. It was why he was stuck in a fish and not landed on an island. I think _Rashi_, as paraphrased in my answer, sufficiently addresses that difference.

Comment: i think the question was what is the need for a miracle. the asker gave the alternative of an island which is non-miraculous

Answer (score 2):

Being trapped inside a fish is a greater miracle, because you can't survive without oxygen, but Yonah survived there without oxygen (see [Malbim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39981&st=&pgnum=136)).

Comment: I think the question was why do you need a miracle in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and look at the message of the entire book. G-d tells Jonah, "go rebuke Nineveh." Jonah doesn't want to, because he's concerned with his reputation as a prophet; because how it will work out with history (Nineveh is the capital of Assyria, which will later attack Israel; and besides, it will make Israel look bad for not responding to rebuke). G-d's retort is to have the entire natural world turn topsy-turvy on Jonah -- storm, fish, gourd, you name it -- to prove a point. If you try making all sorts of calculations, even for the best of reasons, to defy the will of G-d, then the world stops functioning as we know it.